# How to conditionally render a dialog and drawer in material UI for different screen resolutions?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show a dialog in a desktop view and a drawer with the same content in the mobile view.

I am using Material UI as a component library and I am using the Drawer and Dialog component of it.

Please share if you have done something like this, or if you have taken a different approach to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

just need to add `resize` event on your component like so :

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('resize' , this.handleResize)
}

handleResize = (event) => {
   if(window.innerWidth < 400) {
     // handle your component changes
   }
}

// dont forget to remove your event listener on component unmount

componentWillUnMount() {
  document.removeEventListener('resize',this.handleResize)
}
```

and if you using hooks :

```
useEffect(() => {
   document.addEventListener('resize' , handleResize);

   return () => {
     document.removeEventListener('resize',handleResize);
  }
})

const handleResize = (event) => {
   if(window.innerWidth < 400) {
     // handle your component changes
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: please check it as right answer if it was useful

Comment: I will surely do, just waiting for few more answers